# Modal not popping up on calling

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I have a enquiry modal form that I want to be popped up when an image 'Enquire now' is clicked. I have implemented the code but the modal window does not opens up at all. I don't understand what is going wrong. I am a novice to design part, need some insights.Any help will be really helpful Here is my code on `index-morning.html`,

```
   <div class="tfnwidget hidden-xs" id="enquire_widget">
      <!--Modal-->
        <style>
        .modal-notify .modal-header {
        border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    }
    .modal-notify .modal-content {
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
        </style>
             <div class="modal fade" id="register" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-notify modal-warning" role="document">
        <!--Content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <!--Header-->
          <div class="modal-header text-center">
            <h4 class="modal-title white-text w-100 font-weight-bold py-2">Reach us</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <!--Body-->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="md-form mb-5">
              <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
              <input type="text" id="form3" class="form-control validate">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form3">Name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-form">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
              <input type="email" id="form2" class="form-control validate">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form2">Email</label>
            </div>

             <div class="md-form">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
              <input type="mobile" id="form2" class="form-control validate">
              <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form2">Mobile</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!--Footer-->
          <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning waves-effect">Send <i class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.Content-->
      </div>
    </div>
```

and I have `modal.js` file where on image click i have implemented this code,

```
$('#enquire_widget').click(function(){

        location.href = 'index-morning.html#register';

    });
```

Comment: Since the modal you used must be from Bootstrap, I suggest looking at their [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal) on how to open the modal. Regardless, you script is not really the way in opening the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code -

```
$('#enquire_widget').click(function(){
    $('#register').modal('show')
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kamlesh. The CSS applied on the modal is not shjowing up. I mean the colors and design.

Comment: I only have the code written in `<style>` as CSS. I havent written anything else. You can check in my question. What else I need to write?

Comment: Did it. Still no result. Is there any files I need to include into the html?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have used bootstrap for modal,
You need to close "enquire_widget" before creating modal div.
there is "data-toggle" and "data-target" attributes provided by bootstrap to open modal

```
<div class="tfnwidget hidden-xs" id="enquire_widget" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register">Open modal</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The form does not shows up any CSS. What else could be wrong

Comment: Your css is being applied. Add Overflow hidden to your class.
.modal-notify .modal-content {
    border-radius: 3px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: Tried that too. No success . Something else can be done?

Comment: It worked for me in fiddle.
 https://jsfiddle.net/nithinshetty/z5d04gru/7/

Comment: I think the fiddle you posted is still not the original one that I want it to be. The colors are missing and the CSS on button is missing